# Convert IndianStandardTime into ISO8601 format in android

Tags: android

In my android application i need to do some time convertion.i.e. i need to change Indian format like `10-30-2013 12:39` into ISO8601 format like `2013-10-30T12:39:09+0530`.How could i do that?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.getTimeZone();



static SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public static String convertDateYMD(String date){
    Log.v(Util.TAG,"date>>"+date);
    String newDate=null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdfYMD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
    try {
        Date _d = sdfYMD.parse(date); //string to date
        newDate = timeStampFormat.format(_d); //date to string
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    Log.e(Util.TAG,"conerted date:"+newDate);
    return newDate;
}
```

Comment: If i use your code im getting "org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo["IST",mRawOffset=19800000,mUseDst=false]" as time zone.From that how could i get format like "2013-10-30T12:39:09+0530"

Comment: @sanjay Try this c.getTime(); c.getTimeInMillis();

Comment: if i use your code im getting "Tue Oct 29 15:42:21 GMT+05:30 2013"
but i need to get like "2013-10-30T12:39:09+0530"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by studing [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)